# Which is better to use for elastic search in spring boot elastic-search or spring-data-elasticsearch.?

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I want to use elastic search in my project, But I'm a bit confused about using elastic search.

1. Should I use spring-data-elasticsearch or Elastic search.?
2. If I'm using spring-data- elasticsearch, then is it required to install elastic search on local.?
3. I have build a demo spring boot project, But whenever, I want to run, it gives me an error that elasticSearch template is not available.

PS:  I'm seeking answers for guidance. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the new [Java high level REST client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high.html), that's the newest and best way to use java and elasticsearch together.

Comment: I want to use it with Spring Boot. And it also provides Spring-data-elasticsearch. And another issue is, it supports only elastic search 5.x, but the current version is 6.x

Comment: The high level rest client was released with 6.0, everything else is on the path to being deprecated.